# display flex,how to align in center of block?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i am learning display flex,and i have some issue that i cant figure out.
I am trying to align my grid-items in center of cross axis,but something wrong and its not work.

```
.grid-container
  display: flex
  border: 5px solid red
  align-content: center
  justify-content: space-around
  height: 300px
  width: 50%
  .grid-element
    height: 100px
    background: green
```

Here is codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/grOjrO

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Comment: this tool could help you understand how flex works: http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Comment: @Aziz Thanks too!Cool tool!